# Elegant way to map an DTO object graph back to an Entity Framework object graph in a Client/Server app

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have a client/server application where the server uses Entity Framework as the ORM.
Every entity that is to be sent to the client is represented by a DTO-class.

The mapping between the Entity Framework and DTO-classes is handled using AutoMapper.

Let's say we have the following Tables:

Person (string Name, int CountryID)
Country (int CountryID, int Population, string Name)

They are represented by the following EF classes:

```
class Person
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int CountryID { get; set; }
 public Country Country { get; set;}
}

class Country
{
 public int CountryID { get; set; }
 public int Population { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Which in turn are represented by the following DTOs:

```
class PersonDTO
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public CountryDTO Country { get; set;}
}

class CountryDTO
{
 public int CountryID { get; set; }
 public int Population { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

The initial state of the database represents an empty Person-Table and a Country-table that has one entry: (1, 123, 'CountryXYZ')

The clients' app task is to create a new Person Entity and attach its Country-Reference to the available 'CountryXYZ' Country-Entity.

In order to do so, the client app first requests the available CountryDTOs.
It then creates a new PersonDTO instance and sets its Country Property to the only CountryDTO that it has received from the server.
This PersonDTO-instance is then being sent back to the server.
The server in turn maps the PersonDTO-instance back to a Person-instance.

The last servers step is now to store the Person-instance in the ObjectContext and call ObjectContext.SaveChanges().

The problem I have with this approach is that as soon as I call ObjectContext.SaveChanges(), a new Country-row is created in the database instead of just using the available Country-row.
What am I missing here?

I am new to EF and I think this use case is pretty common... so I hope there is an easy fix to this.

In case the problem description is not clear enough please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that client will always use country it already received from your server (it is existing one) you can simply modify your saving logic to use:

```
objectContext.PersonSet.AddObject(personToSave);
objectContext.ObjectStateManager
             .ChangeObjectState(personToSave.Country, EntityState.Unchanged);
objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you use `AddObject` method the entity and all its relations are marked as added and will be inserted to the database as new objects unless you reconfigure their state.

Your entity also exposes FK property so you can use FK property when you map your DTO back to entity instead of creating country instance. In such case you will not need to deal with changing the state of relation because that relation will be represented only through integer column.

If client can create both `Person` and `Country` in single call you will need some flag in your DTO to differ between existing or new entity or you will have to query database to verify if such `Country` already exists.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav. Is there a way to mark the object graph as Modified without having to traverse the whole tree?

Comment: @TwinHabit: No you must always mark all objects you want to process as modified.

Comment: I've got a new problem with this approach when I try to change a referenced Country-Instance of a person. I call PersonSet.AddObject(personToSave); which marks the Person as well as its referenced Country-reference as "Added". Then I want to mark its referenced Country-object as "Modified" by calling ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState. Unfortunately, this throws an Exception telling me, that there is already a Country-Instance in the Object Context. Any idea?

Comment: The exception must be thrown when you use `AddObject` not when you change the state. Are you using new context instance for every operation?

Comment: As soon as the server receives the DTO it translates it to the EF-instance and calls PersonSet.AddPerson(person); This person might now reference a newly created instance of a Country (I can determine whether thats the case by looking at the Countrys ID.). If it is NOT a new instance I call ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(person.Country, EntityState.Modified). That throws: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.Any clue what is going on here?

Comment: Edit: To make this reproducible, my Person can now reference several Countries - not only one anymore.

Comment: That means that you already have country with such Id attached to your context prior to adding the person. It must not happen or whole your scenario will become far more complex.

Comment: Actually I don't.. the ObjectContext is empty. I then add my Person-instance which is referenced by two separate Country-instances. I then go ahead and try to set both Country-instance to "Modified"... which causes this exception... It looks like the self tracking entities really are the way to go in such a scenario..

Comment: Are you sure that those two country instances don't have the same Id (PK)? This problem can happen with STEs as well.

Comment: I am sure, yes. The initial situation in the database is one Person and two Countries. However, there is a change in the database model now: The Country table carries a PersonID-ForeignKey in order to support a 1-n (Person-Country) Relationship (Please note: I know this would not make sense in a RW scenario). Client receives the whole object graph, changes the Name of the two assigned Countries to something arbitrary, sends the graph back, server adds the graph by adding the Person to the PersonSet, tries to set Modified on all 3 instances and... Exception.. do you see a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance where using the [Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx) would probably be useful to you.

It uses a T4 template to generate your entity classes, and they can be round-tripped across the wire using WCF. However, you need to share the assembly that contains the entities on the client and the server.

If you are in control of both, and you are using .Net for both, I would go that route.

Comment: @ChrisWue - Thanks man. Turns out mobile doesn't support Markdown :(